# "rm: descend into directory" - what does it mean?

Tags: linux, emacs, rm

I am trying to follow instructions [here](http://www.braveclojure.com/basic-emacs/) to get emacs going but I am stuck with deleting the `.emacs.d` folder. What do I do when the command line asks:

> rm: descend into directory '.emacs.d'?

```
a@b:~$ sudo rm -r -i .emacs.d
[sudo] password for a: 
rm: descend into directory `.emacs.d'?
```

Is there a simpler way to find and delete files without using the command line? I am unable to locate this file in GUI.

Comment: Try adding the -f option

Comment: @DerHochstapler The -f option did not help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are adding the `-i` option which means `--interactive` so it **will ask you if it can delete each file and directory**. Is the only reason why *"descend into directory `.emacs.d'?"* appears.

So you either, *forget about the `-i`* or keep pressing <kbd>Y</kbd>.

BTW, `sudo` is not necessary:

> (Optional) delete the .emacs.d/.git directory. You'll probably want to create your own git repo for .emacs.d

Delete only implies:

```
rm -r .emacs.d/.git
```

Comment: I am in docker container and I do not provide `-i` option, but it asks me anyway

Comment: @EugenKonkov do you have `alias rm='rm -i'` or `rm() { rm -i $@ }` or something similar in your rc/profile? Try `type rm` to see, or `which -a rm`

Comment: @phuclv: As far as I know: No

Answer (score 3):

It appears that .emacs.d is a folder, and the rm command is asking to confirm that you want to delete the files within the folder as well. To confirm this prompt, type y (for yes) and press enter.

Out of interest, why are you using sudo on this command? The files are in your home directory, so you do not need root privlages to delete them (unless the permissions are messed up)

Comment: Thanks, I tried without sudo and it all worked. Previously, it was asking if I was the root, probably that's why I was using sudo.

Comment: @Zeynel exactly what you used? Also, if it worked mark it the answer as accepted.